# Detecting codes within a certain alphabetical sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I work with language codes, especially with the [ISO 639-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-3) standard, which uses three letter codes to represent languages (`eng` for English, `jpn` for Japanese, etc).

However, codes in the range of `qaa–qtz` are *not* proper language codes but are just empty ones that the user has to define.So, `qaa`, `qab`...`qaz`, `qba`, and so on.

**I was wondering how to write code that would be able to detect if a code is part of this series?** In these codes, the last letter goes all the way through a-z, then starts at a new sequence in the second letter. Kind of like a three digit number, except instead of 0-9 digits, it's a-z letters.

Comment: A regular expression could handle this trivially. See the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: This seems trivial, even without knowing anything about regex: `code[0] == 'q' and 'a' <= code[1] < 'u'`, or, if you're already converting from codes to numbers, something like `num in range(code_to_num('qaa'), code_to_num('qua'))`. Is there some reason the obvious possibilities don't work for you?

Comment: Also, aren't there libraries for this on PyPI already? It seems like a common enough thing that there would be.

Comment: @abarnert There is [one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso-639) but it's outdated (about three years old).

Comment: What about [`pycountry`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycountry/18.2.23)? As far as I can tell, the one you linked to is a fork of (part of) `pycountry` by someone who didn't like one of the changes they may about 3 years ago (and it's also relicensed from LGPL to AGPL, which could be a problem if your main program is not AGPL-compatible).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily with a regular expression matching for the pattern 'q[a-t][a-z]'

```
    import re
    a = ['abc','qaa','qbc','qtz','q12','qua','qabx']
    for i in a:
        if re.match('q[a-t][a-z]',i) and len(i) == 3:
            b = 'MATCH'
        else:
            b = 'NO MATCH'
        print('{} : {}'.format(i,b))
```

edit: forgot to do a length check. Without it the regex would find a positive match on 'qabx' which doesn't fit the pattern you are wanting.

Comment: No need for a length check, just put `^` at the front of your pattern and `$` at the end.